# Taking control of external android application

Tags: android, scripting

As the title is about, I'm just wondering if there is any ways/chances to take control of an android application by other application which has root permission.

For example, I have one application which sends SMS to other cellphones. I want a program (pc program, another android application, whatever) which can force that application to send SMS.

P/s: I know I can create my own sending SMS application but it's not what the question is about. I also already know about a way of using auto click and click on that application via emulators. I dont want that solution, I want a kind of standalone program. No matter how hard it is to build that program.

Comment: Yes, I believe there must be a way - I've seen Helium Backup with root access or with debug access granted to its desktop program opening system backup dialogs and automatically pressing buttons on them. I don't really know where to start looking at how to do that, but at least knowing it's possible tells you you're not wasting your time trying.

Comment: Thank you @Niall for sharing your thought. It's good to hear that there is a possible way to do it. Do you know any definition of something which is related to this topic? So I can do research about it.

Comment: Some best practice advice do not use a sharedUID

Comment: Can you give more details @FredGrott? I dont quite get your idea. Sorry about that.

Comment: its a security issue and not recommended practicee

Comment: I know it's a security issue but is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can launch an android application via [intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

```
Intent smsapp;
try {
 smsapp = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("smsapp package name");
 if (smsapp == null)
  throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
 smsapp.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
 startActivity(smsapp);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
 // smsapp not found
}
```

You can automate user inputs via the busybox applet "input":

[image: excerpt from adb shell]

**Example:**

ADB Shell:

[image]

Meanwhile on my phone:

[image]